# Why can't I see votes even with 1k reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, upvotes, privileges

I recently earned the privilege to see votes by crossing 1k. However, I still can't see votes. For instance, one of my answers got downvoted but all I see is a 1? How can I see votes?

Comment: Did you click on the score?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm new to SO so had no idea how. Thanks again!

Comment: This question should be tagged as support, not discussion.

Comment: It’s explained in the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) that you should’ve seen in a notification: _“You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post.”_ — did you read that?

Comment: Interestingly enough, this very question is a good example of a disputed score itself.

Comment: @NelsonGon You're new to SO but still have 1k rep?  Sigh...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to click the score count.

[image]

Note: Even you don't have 1,000 reputations, you can view vote count using [“View Vote totals” without 1000](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) rep script.

Comment: ISTR that the reason for requiring a click on the vote count is to keep the load on the database down. ICBW.

Comment: Somehow, the combination of your username with the gloriously explicit, idiot-friendly picture got a chuckle of me.